# Create react app with browserify has error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I am learning React and try to create a simple React application.
I want to use ES2015 modules and some ES6 features so I installed Babel and browserify via npm.

These are node modules that I installed:

- babel
- babel-preset-es2015
- babel-preset-react
- babelify
- browserify
- gulp
- reactify
- vinyl-buffer
- vinyl-source-stream
- react
- react-dom

I want to make script into several files (like itemComponent as React) and merge them into dist/app.js that actually website loads. For this, I used gulp!

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return browserify('./source/' + file)
    .transform(babelify, { presets: ["es2015", "react"] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(file))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Gulp is actually working well, everything is transpiled good without error. But check the website, it says:

> app.js:19474 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

So I removed react and react-dom installed via npm, and just download React and load from HTML simply just use script tag, and it works.
But I want to include react like this:

```
import React from 'react';
```

But it is not working. This is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ItemList from './components/itemlist';

let items = [ ... ];

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>List of items:</h1>
                <ItemList items={this.props.items} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I don't know what is the problem and I don't want to load each react file using script tag. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Are you sure that you import `React` in all your JSX files? This bug could happens, when JSX transpiled to `React.createElement...`, and there is no `React` in local scope. For example, if you have `<h1>Hello<h1>`, it will be transpiled to `React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello")`, so you need to be sure, that you have `React` in scope.

Comment: thanks Nikolai! i forgot to import React each seperated file! it works!

Comment: Please post the solution and mark this question as answered if you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of this issue were I forgot to import React module in child components, .

JSX will transpile to something like React.createElement, but there wasn't React exists so that's why I have Reference Error.